# jQuery with Rails - Not doing function inside submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `.submit()` method to send data.

What I have is a question form with alternatives, when I click on one it automatically updates on the DB using this:

application.js

```
function save_response_with_ajax(t){
    $('#edit_response_set_' + t).submit();
  }
```

and the radio button is this:

```
<%= rs_a_form.input :answer_id,
            :collection => "code that gets the info",
            :as => :radio, 
            :input_html => {
     :onclick => 'save_response_with_ajax(' + response_set.id.to_s + ');'} %>
```

Everything works fine, but when I click a lot of times that radio button, the form renders again so I was looking how to avoid multiple ajax requests (only one even if I click a lot of times) and I have to use $.ajax() method. 
The problem is when I write :

```
function save_response_with_ajax(t){
  $("#form").submit(function(){
       //it suppose to be $.ajax(url, .....) instead of alert
       // I'm just testing 
       alert("hi");
  });
}
```

nothing happens.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: First of all you should use remote form - it's easy and you don't have to write own JS. But in my opinion in this case your problem is nested submit event in click event. In save_response_with_ajax method you should do 2 things, first disabled button and then do some stuff with ajax.

Comment: Yes I'm using remote, the main problem is the multiple ajax call I could make if a click a lot of times (it's a sort of a bug, because if they click a lot, it will render again a lot of forms)

Comment: so what's the problem disabling button after first click? Add to your submit button option :disable_with => “Submitting…”

Comment: That's the problem... there's no button =) it automatically saves after click on the alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid multiple submits, you can use [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) to trigger functions when AJAX requests start and end etc.

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   //add js to disable your inputs so you can not trigger the submit again.
  })
  .ajaxStop(function(){
   //add js to re-enable your inputs that you disabled in ajaxStart
  })
  .ajaxError(function(){
   //add js here to alert user that a problem occurred.
  });
```